# fix table position

Tags: tables

In fact, I have tried all methods to fix the table position, but it goes after a section knowing that this table must be before the section, here is the code:

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{title}
\begin{tabular}{@{} c@{\hskip 0.25in} c@{\hskip 1.5in} c@{\hskip 0.25in} c  @{}}
\toprule
 Parameters & Value & Parameters & Value   \\
\midrule
$f^{*}(Hz)$ & 50 & $ X $ & 1.61 \\  \\

$E^{*}(V)$ & 220 & $ Y $ & 1.61\\ \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

How can I solve this problem

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text Edit: alternatively https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned

Comment: the only purpose of the table environment is to specify that its content may be moved.